# AJAX FormData submit fails with the word "DEL"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Today I had a problem with the register of an user call "Del Campo", the AJAX fails always that the input text have the word "DEL" and I get 403 Forbidden. The reproducible error here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h1>AJAX FAIL WITH "DEL CAMPO"</h1>

<form id="form">
    Input: <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">
    <button type="button" onclick="send()">Send</button>
</form>

<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    function send() {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
        formData.append('accion', 'addEmpresario');

        $.ajax({
                url: 'TEST_SCREEN_DB.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            })
            .done(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log('fail');
            })
            .always(function() {

            });
    }
</script>
```

The url does not matter because the AJAX fails even with a fake url

Comment: If you're getting a 403 response that's a server side error. It's telling you that you don't have permission to access the endpoint you're calling. Check that you're including an necessary authentication/authorisation headers in the request, and debug your PHP code from there

Comment: Yes but the AJAX works if I remove the word "DEL" that is the problem.

Comment: Can  `TEST_SCREEN_DB.php` return a 403 status if you don't have permission to delete that user?

Comment: Remove the word DEL from... where? In any case, the problem is in your PHP code, not the JS.